# How to keep special characters when renaming a file using AppleScript

Tags: excel, encoding, applescript, filenames

I've got an AppleScript file to replace filenames which are supplied through a CSV file. While I've got the script to work, it has issues with encoding of the strings/filenames.

The finding of files works perfectly. Renaming it to something like Malmö results in a very weird encoded string.

The CSV originates from Microsoft Excel, and I suspect is not properly UTF-8 encoded. And now I'm stuck in how to handle the encoding properly. (or how to convert the encoding). As far as I know it has the default Excel encoding ISO 8859-1.

```
set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select the CSV file")
set thePath to (choose folder with prompt "Select directory") as string
set theCSVData to paragraphs of ((read theFile))

set {oldTID, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, ";"}
repeat with thisLine in theCSVData
    set {oldFileName, newFileName} to text items of thisLine
    if length of oldFileName > 0 then
        set oldFile to thePath & oldFileName
        set newFile to newFileName
        tell application "System Events"
            if exists file oldFile then
                set name of file oldFile to newFile
            end if
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
```

So my question is, how do I fix the encoding issue, either by reading it properly or by encoding the file first (through applescript)

Answer (score 0):

I really think the filenames are encoded using utf16LE, but I can be wrong. Anyhow, there is a utility you can access via Terminal, that is named **iconv** (man iconv), that you can experiment with, and maybe re-encode the filename with. If you receive the output from a `do shell script` as text, or unicode text, then you get back utf16, so it won't be corrupted after the conversion. (Before you use it as a filename).

Comment: could you give me an example how to convert the CSV file from `utf16LE` to `utf-8`? Or how to convert the strings that I get from it, using applescript? I'm not very familiar with either

Comment: I meant that the hfs filenames on the **disk** is encoded in utf16Le. I think foo, has given you a full and correct answer, to what I meant, (or even more correct, because I was thinking of encoding the filenames through iconv one by one.) Now, if you convert the csv to utf-8 and take it from there, then all characters, should really be fine, (I use æøå, and it never fails).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
set theCSVData to paragraphs of ((read theFile as «class utf8»))
```

Comment: I'm afraid that results in the exact same deformed strings. Like `J‰rf‰lla ` and `Malmˆ`

Comment: Make sure the CSV is also saved as UTF8. If you can only save it in ISO8859-1, run `iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF8 '/path/to/file.csv' > '/path/to/file-utf8.csv'` in Terminal to convert it to UTF8 encoding first.

Comment: hmm that turns the file into a 0-byte file

Comment: Try this: `iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 '/path/to/file.csv' > '/path/to/file-utf8.csv'` I have changed the encoding parameters a little, by adding some dashes, and it works for me.